# Rxjs Observable run sequentially and return an array

Tags: rxjs, observable

```
var arr = [obs1, obs2, obs3];
Observable.forkJoin(...arr).subscribe(function (observableItems) {})
```

Runs observables in parallel and return an array.

How can I run the observables sequentially **and** return an array. I do not want to get called for each observable, so `concat()` is not appropriate for me.

I want to receive the same final result as `forkJoin` but run sequentially.

Does it exist? or do I have to code my own observable pattern?

Comment: It seems that you're looking for merge ... (even tho it does not return an array)

Comment: Why concat is not an option? - You can call toArray on concatenation result.

Comment: Concat is not an option because he wants them to run in //, concat will not run them in //

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just use `concat` and then `toArray`:

```
var arr = [obs1, obs2, obs3];
Observable.concat(...arr).toArray().subscribe(function (observableItems) {})
```

If you need behavior, more similar to `forkJoin`(to get only last results from each observables), as @cartant mentioned in comment: you will need to apply `last` operator on observables before concatenating them:

```
Observable
  .concat(...arr.map(o => o.last()))
  .toArray()
  .subscribe(function (observableItems) {})
```

Comment: You're going to need to use the `last` operator with the source observables, as `forkJoin` emits an array of the obserfables' final values and `concat` will emit the entire stream of values.

Comment: yes, good point - you are right, behavior is a bit different. will add this to answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can throw away my custom Subscriber/Observable pattern I wrote! @cartant gets some brownie points.