# Sending sequential Http Requests using RXJS Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, concatmap

I would to have a function which sends an http request to an endpoint giving the list of all items, and then sending a second request to get the first element on that list. The function should return the last item. I'm using the following code but the second http request is not working.

```js
getFirstItem(): Observable<any> {
  return this.getList().pipe(concatMap(value => this.getItem(value[0].id)));
}
```

*Using Angular 7 and rxjs 6.4.0*

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: 
When running the following snippet, the second console log never gets called

```
getFirstItem(): Observable<any> {
  return this.getList().pipe(
    tap(x => console.log(x)),
    concatMap(value => this.getItem(value[0].id)),
    tap(x => console.log(x)) // never called
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560652/how-to-make-a-sequence-of-http-requests-in-angular-6-using-rxjs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865820/rxjs-observable-run-sequentially-and-return-an-array

Comment: you question is not clear and code snippets are not enough.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50981109/sequential-cascade-observables-according-result-from-previous-response-and-remap

Comment: I added a few more details to the question, hope its clearer

Comment: How does `getItem()` look like?

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a sequence of http requests in Angular 6 using RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560652/how-to-make-a-sequence-of-http-requests-in-angular-6-using-rxjs)

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. I just wonder how `this.getItem` is implemented.

Anyway here is an working example with concatMap:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-api-call-jvqj5q?file=src/app/app.component.ts

You can use `mergeMap`, `concatMap`, `switchMap`. All of them will work. They just behave differently regarding how the inner Observable (`this.getItem`) is treated when the outer observable emits (`this.getList`).

More info here: https://morioh.com/p/fcfea9850b90

Answer (score -1):

You can use **mergeMap**

```
var result = this.getList().pipe(
  mergeMap(value =>  this.getItem(value[0].id)))
);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but, I'm trying to understand why its not working, not to use another operator

Comment: I think someone punished you for this answer, Your answer is OK but the topic is replicated